# Wordpress, Mouse over posts on index makes them of different size and position

Tags: css, wordpress, post, grid

I have a problem on my wordpress blog with the way posts are shown on the main page, and I think it's due to the size inside css/html, but I don't manage to find a solution. I'm asking for help.

The blog can be found at the URL: http://pavilionmagazine.org

As you can see on the main page, each post has the same size (due to css .post height: 600px; but when you mouse over they change size). I've managed to make the photo size the same, the excerpt to be the same number of characters, and the .post box is 600px high.

However, when you mouse over the posts they change their size and some of them (2nd, 5th, 8th posts from below) switch position. Why is that happening?

Because of each posts' size the grid has errors in it.

Why can't the posts be aligned, occupy the same size and make part of a nice fluent grid?

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

`.post:hover` needs to have a fixed height. Take a look at the two:

```
.post:hover {
height: auto;
}

.post {
height: 600px;
}
```

The auto height of `post:hover` right now is overriding your fixed height on `.post`.

As for position, inspect the two and see what else is being overriding by the hover values. Keep hover overrides to a minimum.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the `.post` boxes height is set to auto on mouseover.

So you have to edit your `style.css` file, line `350` and delete the css rule: `height:auto;`

Also, there are a lot of duplicated css rules on `.post:hover`. You can delete all and try this:

```
.post:hover {
    background-color: #eaeaea;
}
```